# getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath() Throw a null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, class, classloader

I used this line of code in a Java class to retrieve a URI which i used to customize the ClassLoader:

```
String uri = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
```

Now the same line of code in an Android App in the MainActivity to be exact throw a null pointer exception.

Is there something special for Android development ?
Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of `this` at the time? `getClass()` is not a static method.

Comment: Break it down into separate statements and tell us which of those method calls is failing.

Comment: @PM77-1: it's the same we can use `this.getClass()` or `getClass()` it refers to the current loaded class.

Comment: @EJP: yes I do, unfortunately still the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getProtectionDomain()` is not implemented in Android's version of Java

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#getProtectionDomain%28%29

Also, the `ProtectionDomain` class is marked as "Legacy security code; do not use."

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html

I assume this only exists in Android Java to maintain compilation compatibility.

Comment: Rich, you're right. Is there any trick or other solution to do it. I want the URI to load compiled class (.class) in the same path.