# How to get current class filename in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

In Java I can use the following code:

```
public class Ex {
    public static void main(String [ ] args) {
        String path = Ex.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath();
        String decodedPath = URLDecoder.decode(path, "UTF-8");
    }
}
```

but in Kotlin, the main function is defined outside out of a class. How can I get it's current file name?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Would this be the equivalent of getting argv[0] in C?

Answer (score -6, accepted):

The solution is:

```
class Ex() {
    fun m() {
        var p2 = Ex::class.java.simpleName
        println("p2:${p2}")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Ex().m()
}
```

Comment: It's nice that this code solves your problem, but it isn't an answer to your original question. This code returns the name of the Java class, not the name of the file from which it was compiled.

Comment: Agree with @yole, additionally you could call `Ex::class.java.simpleName` directly from the `main`, creating a `Ex` instance doesn't make sense there.

Answer (score 6):

As a workaround, put `main` method into companion object.
This code will show a same path as your Java code:

```
class ExKt {
  companion object {
    @JvmStatic fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val path = ExKt::class.java.protectionDomain.codeSource.location.path
        println("Kotlin: " + path)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: for some reason, protectionDomain returns null for Android Activity class :(

Comment: @Liker777, this code is not compatible with Android runtime. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27790348/getclass-getprotectiondomain-getcodesource-getlocation-getpath-throw-a

Comment: thank you. As an alternative, I got the file name with extension via stacktrace, the remaining thing is how to find a path to that file. Walkaround is recursive search in the package for the file name, but I believe there should be simpler way to return a full path...